# Set up docker-compose in PhpStorm 2017.3.2

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, phpstorm

I created a Docker image that bundles PHP (with Apache), Xdebug and PHPUnit which I can start with docker-compose in the terminal.

```
version: '3'

services:
   php-apache-xdebug-phpunit:
     image: php-apache-xdebug-phpunit:7.2
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     volumes:
       - ./src:/var/www/html
     restart: always
```

I want to use the PhpStorm integration with docker-compose but when I configure the CLI interpreter, I get two errors (screenshot):

- BadRequestException -> invalid environment variable (I think an empty value should be possible actually)
- PHP version: not installed (it's partially visible in the screenshot)

[image: PhpStorm docker-compose config error]

The Dockerfile for completeness sake:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache-stretch

##########
# XDebug #
##########
# Install
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.6.1 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
# Configure
RUN echo 'zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so"' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo "error_reporting = E_ALL" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "display_startup_errors = On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "display_errors = On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.idekey=\"PHPSTORM\"" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

###########
# PHPUnit #
###########
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget
RUN wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-7.4.phar
RUN chmod +x phpunit-7.4.phar
RUN mv phpunit-7.4.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
RUN phpunit --version

###################
# PHP Codesniffer #
###################
RUN curl -OL https://squizlabs.github.io/PHP_CodeSniffer/phpcs.phar
RUN mv phpcs.phar /usr/local/bin/phpcs
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpcs
```

Comment: Check this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36951#comment=27-2267313

Comment: That worked! When you configure PHP remote interpreter with docker-compose, you can add environment variables (which I did not) following 3 dots, you can uncheck "Include parent environment variables" checkbox which included a lot of junk by default.